# SpringBoot Multi-tenant app with scheduled tasks

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, multi-tenant

I've a multi-tenant app where the our customers submit their orders (JSON payload), which has to be processed offline. We're using database per tenant strategy and have configuration working all fine. However for asynchronous processing like in this example, we're stuck. When payload is submitted by the customer, it's saved into a table. We want to run a scheduled task, that can read this table and process the orders in their.

We tried something like:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
    public void doSomething() {
        TenantDataSource tenantDataSource = context.getBean(TenantDataSource.class);
        Set<String> tenants = tenantDataSource.getAll().keySet();
        tenants.forEach(tenant -> {
            MDC.setContext(new CallContext().setTenantId(tenant));
            context.getBean(JobService.class).listJobs();
        });
    }
```

But this still looks for the jobs in the master database and not in the tenant specific database.

Any pointers?

Comment: What's your CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver look like?

Comment: @singhspk: were you able to resolve this issue? If so, it would be great to know how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the doSomething() method isn't transactional as `transactional` would create its own interceptor rather than looking into your resolver.